# Implementing CASL on Front-End and Backend Use Cases

Tags: authentication, authorization, nest, casl

I am trying to implement shared CASL on front end and on the backend side (nestjs). I have multiple use cases:

---

- Admin can read All Posts
- Admin can update All Posts
- Admin can delete All posts
- Admin can View/read the Change Status Button
- Admin can View/read the Add Comment Button

---

- User1 can read his own post
- User1 can update his own post
- User1 can delete his own post
- User1 can View/read the Change Status Button on posts created by himself
- User1 can View/read the Add comment Button on posts created by himself

---

First, I tried to use use-case based permissions for example I created my ability using this:

```
Admin:
    can('read', 'Post');
    can('update', 'Post');
    can('delete', 'Post');
    can('read', 'Change Status');
    can('read', 'Add Comment');

User1
    can('read', 'Post', { createdBy: userId });
    can('update', 'Post', { createdBy: userId });
    can('delete', 'Post', { createdBy: userId });
    can('read', 'Change Status', { createdBy: userId });
    can('read', 'Add Comment', { createdBy: userId });
```

But, I feel that this is not scalable what If I made a typo while checking for permissions? For example, If I check permission using `ability.can(read, 'add comments')` then it will give me that User is not authorized. Also, If I change the name of my `comment` module to `note` then I have to change each and every permission. So, I left this option and then I tried to implement it using **Entities**. For Example. I created my ability using this (Here Post and Comment is an entity):

```
Admin:
    can('read', 'Post');
    can('update', 'Post');
    can('delete', 'Post');
    can('read', 'Comment');

User1
    can('read', 'Post', { createdBy: userId });
    can('update', 'Post', { createdBy: userId });
    can('delete', 'Post', { createdBy: userId });
    can('read', 'Comment', { createdBy: userId });
```

But, I am not sure about this method. In this method, I have multiple Issues

- How can I add checks on the front end so that User1 Can see the `Change Status` and `Add Comment` buttons only on his own Posts?
- On the backend, If there is any endpoint that is not using any entity
  then how to Check for permissions for that endpoint for example, I
  have an endpoint to retrieve some constants but only the `admin` is
  allowed to read those constants.
- On the backend, If I am using joins in my query and User1 does not
  have permission to view the joined table then how to handle this?
- On the backend, If I am changing multiple entities inside 1 endpoint
  then I have to give permission for each entity to User1. That makes this Vulnerable.

I want to check If I am going in the right direction. Also, Is there any better solution for this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks